# trouble connecting signal/slot from QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to C++ and qt creator entirely. I want to click on a folder in the `treeView` and then in response do something with the data inside that directory. For now I'm just trying to get signals/slots connected so I'm only trying to write something inside "testLabel" when a tree item is clicked..
I've been trying for a few hours now, searching forums and documentation, trying various things. The code always does complile but upon clicking, selecting, double clicking nothing happens.
Here's the code:

main_window.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_main_window.h"


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

public slots:
    void on_pushButtonImport_clicked(); // use this to let user choose a directory and update tree
    //void on_treeItem_double_clicked(); // slot to receive signal of treeView.. 
    void labelTest_setText(const QModelIndex& index);

private:
    Ui::MainWindowClass ui;
};
```

main_window.cpp:

```
#include "main_window.h"
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <Qstring>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui.treeView, SIGNAL(QTreeView::doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index)), ui.labelTest, SLOT(labelTest_setText(const QModelIndex & index)));
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonImport_clicked() {
    // let user choose a directory to import
    // possibly change this with a pop up window to choose directory
    QString path_string = ui.textEditDirectory->toPlainText();
    // add error handler if text is not a path
    QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel();
    // show tree structure
    model->setRootPath(path_string);
    ui.treeView->setModel(model);
    ui.treeView->setRootIndex(model->index(path_string));
}

void MainWindow::labelTest_setText(const QModelIndex &index) {
    std::string test_string = "Test success!";
    QString testing = QString::fromStdString(test_string);
    ui.labelTest->setText(testing);
}
```

I have tried putting the connection on the end of the `on_pushButton_clicked()` function because that's when `treeView` gets a model but that yields the same result. I have tried several signals of `treeView` etc, I guess I'm just very unfamiliar with all this and I can't figure out how to connect them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Ui::MainWindowClass ui;` this is usually a pointer, did you manually change this?

Comment: Typo: `SIGNAL(QTreeView::doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index))` --> `SIGNAL(doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index))`?  Better still, use the new [signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_QObject_member).

Comment: Typo: use `QObject::connect(ui.treeView, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(const QModelIndex & index)), ui.labelTest, SLOT(labelTest_setText(const QModelIndex & index)));
`

Comment: I honestly don't know, we've been kinda thrown head first in this project and I'm just winging it. I so far havent had to call anything with ui* but I might have to?

Comment: Qt creator itself always sets `ui` as `ui*`, so this is kind of really surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SIGNAL()` `SLOT()` syntax is old and uses the C++ preprocessor so often times completely invalid things will be compiling just fine. Read more about the new syntax [here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Switch to the modern syntax, which is like:

```
QObject::connect(ui.treeView, &QTreeView::doubleClicked,
                 this, &MainWindow::labelTest_setText);
```

If you still (for some reason) want to use the old syntax, it would be like this:

```
QObject::connect(ui.treeView, SIGNAL(doubleClicked(QModelIndex)),
                 this, SLOT(labelTest_setText(QModelIndex)));
```

This uses the normalized syntax, so that you don't have to write `const QModel& index` in the function arguments, which is inefficient.

Also, this is completely unnecessary and inefficient in Qt:

```
    std::string test_string = "Test success!";
    QString testing = QString::fromStdString(test_string);
```

You should use `QString` directly with `QStringLiteral` (for literals):

```
    QString testing = QStringLiteral("Test success!");
```

Comment: thanks, the modern syntax gives an error that QLabel contains no function labelTest_setText, the old syntax does compile but again does nothing. Sorry i'm still very new to c++ and qt (creator). Thank you for the advice on QString!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated the answer. Try now. I was passing the wrong object in the 3rd argument.

Comment: `labelTest_setText()` function belongs to MainWindow class, so third argument in connect will be `this`

Comment: That does work! Thank you so much, I think i understand connecting a bit better now